# Is it correct to use the word "something" to describe a plural form?

Tags: word-usage, sentence

> Then, as I continued gazing at her, **something** came to my mind. **They**
>   were the remnants of the dream I had before waking up.

Is that grammatically correct? If not, what's the closest alternative?

Comment: Yes. That plural is also an object that can be treated as a singular object, as long as the discrete nature of each is not the focus.  However, not as in the two sentences in the example. Drop the phrase *They were*, and there you are.

Comment: @Kris: I don't think OP is asking whether *the remnants* has to be treated as singular or plural (it can be either, depending on context). His highlighting (and question title) indicate he's asking whether *something* can be treated as plural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not correct. If OP wants to use singular *something* in the first sentence, this must be referenced by a singular form in the second.

Here are a number of written instances of [it is the remnants](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20is%20the%20remnants%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which I think show that *in the right context* there's nothing inherently wrong with treating *the remnants* as a singular noun.

But in OP's context this is unnecessary, To avoid potential accusations of "clumsiness", I would either adopt Kris's suggestion (just drop *they were* completely), or change singular *something* to a more suitable plural (such as *some thoughts* or *ideas*).

Comment: @Kris: On the *grammar* front, yes. But I think the suggestion in your comment would probably far more useful to OP, even though it's really *writing advice* (I didn't upvote the comment because I either misunderstood or disagreed with the first part, but I certainly endorse the final point).

Answer (score 1):

"Then, as I continued gazing at her, the remnants of the dream I had before waking up came to my mind."

It seems odd to me to use the abstraction "something" and then immediately explain clearly what the something was/is. But that is a stylistic point, really. However, avoiding the use of "something" removes the problem of agreement in number with "remnants".